# Open html page in same window after clicking on navlink

Tags: jquery, css

I created a navbar and nav-menu includes list as home, about-us and so on.
when I click on navbar, nav-menu slides down and shows list of navlinks. When I click on navlink eg. about-us, nav menu slides up but about-us page not opens.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">menu<span><img src="images/menu-arrow.png"></span></div>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>Home</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>About us</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html" id="services" class="nav-link"><h1>Services</h1></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav-menu li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
        $('.navbar span img').removeClass('flipped').css({"transition":".5s"});
        $('.nav-menu').animate({'height':'toggle'});
        var url = this.href;
        $(".main-container").load(url);
    });
});
```

I exact wants when I click on navlinks, nav-menu slide up then current page fade out and same time or then targeted page shows.

Comment: Do you intend to load the target url on specific div without reloading the page?

Comment: No, I want whole targeted page load.

Comment: You mean new tab right? I added a fiddle below.

Comment: Sorry, this is not, Please read as - I exact wants when I click on navlinks, nav-menu slide up then current page fade out and same time or then targeted page opens or fade in in same window

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
    $(".nav-menu li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
        $('.navbar span img').removeClass('flipped').css({"transition":".5s"});
        $('.nav-menu').animate({'height':'toggle'});
        var url = this.href;
        window.open(
          url,
          '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">menu<span><img src="images/menu-arrow.png"></span></div>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>Home</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>About us</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html" id="services" class="nav-link"><h1>Services</h1></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I created this fiddle base on the code you provided. Now Obviously you can't run this on the fiddle but

```
window.open(
      url,
      '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
```

will open a new tab for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correct then you just need to added target attribute to your menu links:-

```html
<div class="navbar">menu<span><img src="images/menu-arrow.png"></span></div>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_self" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>Home</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html" target="_self" id="home" class="nav-link"><h1>About us</h1></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html" target="_self" id="services" class="nav-link"><h1>Services</h1></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```